# Ability to add International Addresses

Tags: addresses

Currently, I'm unable to add anything except for U.S. addresses. I'mm using Civi 5.2.3. How can I add international addresses to existing contacts? I've tried Administer menu » Localization » Address Settings but am not able to add a country from there or on the edit page of each contact. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the available countries in Administer>Localization>Language and Currency.